# TabLayout tab title issue

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Please see below images from same phone. Whenever I click anywhere in app it change tab title in app.

[image]
[image]

Why this strange thing happnes. It only in one device (Samsung J2 2018)

**Edit1:**

Real issue is, it is not displaying different. In same device when I change tab it displays like image2 and Again if I tap somewhere It displays like Image1.

If I touch anything on screen It changes from Image1 to Image2 and vice versa.

**Edit2**
If I does not define textsize or If define it 14sp then and only fluctuation occurs.

Comment: did u try **`app:tabMode="scrollable"`**

Comment: I don't want scrollable

Comment: then make text size small.

Comment: but why it is not taking same text size?

Comment: `app:tabMode="fixed"` is used to fix the size of `tabLayout` according to width of mobile screen. It'll give equal width to each tab.

Comment: @AnshulTyagi  But why this strange thing happens, even in one device?

Comment: This only happens in one device, It fluctuate both images.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set small *Text Size* for *small devices*,

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="customTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/AppTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

**TabLayout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    style="@style/customTabLayout"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    .... />
```

Comment: Did you tried with small text size? If no then please once try with that and check in small text size this issue occurs or not.

Comment: I have done same already to solve my issue. but I want to know what happening to this

Answer (score 2):

I cannot send comment so I had to answer

if it will change from image1 to image2 by touching anything on screen I think by changing focus to another view it will be fixed

just use `"focusable"="true"` in layout and in code call `view.requestFocus()`

you had to call `view.requestFocus()` every time tab is changing